# dropdown combo not showing up in formCollection in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

in my asp.net mvc view i have a select dropdown:

```
<select id="userRole" name="userRole" disabled="true">
```

when i submit the form to the controller, i have the following code:

```
    [Authorize]
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Edit(FormCollection    formCollection_)
    {
        string role = formCollection_["userRole"].ToString();
}
```

but when i look into the formCollection object there is no key for "userRole".  Any idea why this would be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should just be

```
 <select id="userRole" name="userRole" disabled>
```

but disabled inputs [will not be part of your FormCollection](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.12.1) "[successful control](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#successful-controls)"

Comment: that is a bit strange.  is there anyway to have a control disabled but still pass it to the controller.  I would like to avoid any klugy hidden fields if possible

Comment: try readonly instead of disabled http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.12.2

Comment: Is <... disabled> valid markup? I think it has to be disabled="disabled"?

Comment: "readonly" will fix the FormCollection issue, however, a "readonly" dropdown is still fully operational (at least in FireFox 12)