# Jquery Textbox Disabled... Cannot See the attribute in FormCollection

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

My Project is ASP.NET MVC one. In the view I am creating a Html Textbox and disabling it in the javascript using attr.

```
<script language="javascript">
Disable= function(){
  $("#Disable").attr("disabled","disabled");
}
</script>
<% using(Html.BeginForm("Save","Account")){%>
<%: Html.TextboxFor(model=>model.Account) %>
<input type="button" id="Disable" name="Disable" onclick="Disable()">
<input type="submit" id="Save">
<%}%>
```

When 'Save' button is hit I am catching the values in the FormCollection. But I could not see the Textbox in the collection when its get disabed. When it doesn't it works fine. Why does this happen?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245477/dropdown-combo-not-showing-up-in-formcollection-in-controller

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disabled fields are not posted.  you can have a hidden field that holds the value if you need it posted.

Comment: For the Textbox case hidden field works...but if have a grid and every column has checkboxes and textboxes in it. If I check the checkbox, textbox should be disabled. Then if I get the FormCollection it doesnot show up for that row, how could I deal this case.

Comment: Or when you disable the fields, could you add the hidden field to the cell:
$("#Disable").attr("disabled","disabled");
var hid = $('<input name= type="hidden" name="" name="'+$("#Disable").attr('name')+'"/>').val($("#Disable").val());
cell.append(hid);

Answer (score 0):

I've written a [blog post](http://blog.js-development.com/2008/09/revised-changed-values-of-readonly-and.html) some years ago about this issue.

The idea is to mark it as readonly and add a CSS class that eventually makes it appear as disabled. Then in the postback you may be able to access the value through the Request[yourTextBox.UniqueID].

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in an app I'm building. I didn't want to mark the fields as readonly, since that left the comboboxes enabled. So, I just added a call to a JavaScript function on my submit button that re-enables the controls.

```
<input type="submit" name="Save" value="Save" onclick="enableControls(); return true;"/>
```

The enableControls() function:

```
function enableControls() {
    $('input[type="text"], textarea, input[type="checkbox"], select').attr('disabled', false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Formcollection you cannot get the values of diabled input or select alternative way is hide them like below

```
  <div><input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="classId" name="classId" autocomplete="off" placeholder="class id"/></div>
```